# Getting a Dockerised site to run behind Traefik reverse proxy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have Traefik v1.7.6 installed as a Docker container following the instructions in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-traefik-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Everything works fine and that site is accessed at: https://proxy.hostname.com

I want to add a UniFi Controller container to run behind this reverse proxy, but need help with my configuration.

Following [this tutorial](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/install-unifi-controller-on-docker/), I am able to create a functional container and access this site at: https://unifi.hostname.com:8443

Port 8443 is the native web management port that UniFi runs on, but this is where is I need help.

From my understanding I should be able to access this site via Traefik at https://unifi.hostname.com and be directed to the proper 8443 port on the back end. Secondly the benefit of using Let's Encrypt is lost as it only provides a certificate to subdomains on port 443.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.6"
services:

  unifi:
    hostname: unifi
    image: linuxserver/unifi:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: "unifi"
    volumes:
      - /docker/unifi:/config
    ports:
      - target: 3478
        published: 3478
        protocol: udp
        mode: host
      - target: 10001
        published: 10001
        protocol: udp
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8081
        published: 8081
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8443
        published: 8443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8880
        published: 8880
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 6789
        published: 6789
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - proxy
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/New_York
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.tags=frontend"
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
      - "traefik.admin.backend=unifi"
      - "traefik.admin.frontend.rule=Host:unifi.hostname.com"
      - "traefik.admin.port=8443"
      - "traefik.admin.protocol=https"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Comment: I assume from your question that `https://unifi.hostname.com/` is not working as you expect. Do you get anything in your Traefik logs when trying to connect to that address? What happens if you point your browser to that URL?

Comment: https://unifi.hostname.com/ results in a "Bad Gateway" response, but does have a valid certificate. https://unifi.hostname.com:8443 works, but does not have a valid certificate.

Comment: This may be something that folks need to download and try - this stuff can be rather fiddly. I have added a bounty on it.

Answer (score 4):

From my own experience, proxying UniFi Controller has been a pain because it uses a baked-in, self-signed certificate. Typically you have to instruct your proxy to ignore invalid certs when it connects to its backend.

I'd suggest that what you want is the `InsecureSkipVerify` option, which has to be enabled in `traefik.toml`.

> insecureSkipVerify : If set to true invalid SSL certificates are accepted for backends.
>   Note: This disables detection of man-in-the-middle attacks so should only be used on secure backend networks.
>   - https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/commons/

Comment: If UniFi runs in a Docker container, could a user use a volume to overwrite the self-signed cert with a real one?

Comment: @halfer no, it’s built deep into the package (java IIRC)

Comment: Oh, fair enough. Still, Traefik could be configured to receive an encrypted connection on a valid cert, and then its connection to UniFi could be insecure in the backend, as long as the path between Traefik and UniFi is not susceptible to interception.

Comment: [This is a potentially related thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubiquiti/comments/75ir69/unifi_ssl_certificate/).

Comment: @halfer exactly :) That’s the reason for the InsecureSkipVerify directive above. Personally, I use traefik -> oauth_proxy (plaintext) -> UniFi Controller (self-signed) to add another layer of authentication

Comment: Adding "InsecureSkipVerify = true" to the traefik.toml yields an "Internal Server Error" when attempting to access unifi.hostname.com, but does have a valid cert. unifi.hostname.com:8443 still works, but does not have a valid certificate

Comment: @TParker31: you've added that information in comments under the question, so the author here is probably aware of it. Would you expand on that? I wonder if an edit is required to the question.